# Postfix + MySQL + dovecot + postfixadmin - mail arrive to local users

Tags: 14.04, postfix, mail, dovecot

I'm trying to set up a mail server with virtual users.

I can:

- login in roundcube,
- send mail to gmail

*but* when I send messages to my own domain, the mails arrive to local users.

Mail was in /var/mail, but in postfix and dovecot config files are in /var/vmail

*Postfix configuration:*

```
postconf -n

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = example.com, example.ovh.net, localhost.ovh.net, localhost
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = example.com
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = $mynetworks
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/mycompany/mailserver/mail-cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/mycompany/mailserver/mail-key.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/spool/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 150
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:150
```

*Dovecot Configuration:*

```
doveconf -n

# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64-vps x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ext4
auth_debug = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
first_valid_uid = 150
last_valid_uid = 150
mail_gid = mail
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_uid = vmail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@example.com
protocols = " imap"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = mail
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
```

/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

```
user = mail
password = password
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mail
table = mailbox
select_field = CONCAT(domain, '/', local_part)
where_field = username
additional_conditions = and active = '1'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: try to set virtual_transport = virtual and post the output of the sql query in this file /etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

Comment: I'm restore defaults settings and I'm install using this https://www.exratione.com/2014/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1404-postfix-dovecot-mysql/

Comment: question solved?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure if this works for you, but try to set the driver of your userdb to static and use set the arguments as follows in your dovecot configuration:

```
    userdb {
      args = uid=vmail gid=mail home=/var/vmail/%d/%n
      driver = static
    }
```

Just a suggestion.
Ulli